# The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Before encountering my current issue, I had successfully run several simple applications like 'Guess the Number' and 'Currency Converter'. A week ago, I ran an application called 'Connect 3 Game' which worked fine. I then pushed the application to GitHub. When I reopened and tried to run the application again, I encountered this problem for the first time.

I was surprised because the application had been working just a minute ago. As a troubleshooting step, I tried changing the Gradle version, but that didn't solve the issue. I also deleted all the Gradle versions from '$/.gradle/wrapper/dists/' and ran the application again, but to no avail.

Next, I manually set up the Gradle path by navigating to 'Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle' and choosing 'Specified Location' from 'Use Gradle From'. After doing this, I ran the application and it worked.

However, when I exited Android Studio and reopened it to run the application again, I encountered the error once more. Even reinstalling Android Studio didn't resolve the issue.

Now, ***if I create an application, it works initially. But as soon as I exit Android Studio and reopen it to run the application again, I see the error.*** Any help would be appreciated.